# XML and Android Java Mobile

Tags: java, android, xml

I am currently using Android SDK with Eclipse to make some Android App..
I found that anyone could use XML instead Visual programming in Eclipse so my question is :

Why XML is used in Android Java Programming 
From my checking about XML .. it is a language used to transfer data over internet .. is that true and what is the relation with Android JAVA Programming 
Thanks

Comment: To help your understanding, XML is not a language.  Nor is it "code".  It is nothing more than data.  It is used to transfer data over the internet (as well as a lot of other uses) but so is PNG, and .txt, and .PDF and HTML and a thousand other data types.  In Android, layout XML is nothing more than data describing to the layout engine which objects to create and their properties.  When you inflate the layout (e.g. using setContentview(), an XML parser reads the XML and creates objects which it attaches to your view.  You can use XML, or code, or visual.  Whatever's comfortable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon ... actually , your description is awesome ..
I have understood that XML could be regarded as "data description tool" ??
So I could encode any type of data to be in the XML format ??
Is that true ??

Comment: Yes. A common use in Android is to create custom view objects with their own properties and then to add those views to the layout XML.  The properties can have any type of data that can be represented as string inside the XML  - which, with the right encoding/escaping, can be anything!  Because of OOP, you can even extend existing views and add your own properties which are set alongside the other properties in the XML - e.g. `<MyTextView android:text="some text" myNameSpace:myProperty="some value which is whatever I want"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml and java are related in android like .. all the back end activity's (back - end code) is handle by the java and xml is use for the view. XML is back bone of android application you can use it for creating view very easily you can also do same thing with the java class it self. But for the performance and fast development recommendation of XML and JAVA activity class coupling.

Its is same as we have xml in many other frame works in java like JUDDI, AXIS2 web-services and STRUTS , Hibernate . But the use of xml in android is different in the android you can use XML for the you views of the layout.